# jquery remove trailing blank space in text input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a signup form that requires an email. when a user uses an android device and enters their email, if they have used the device before android auto suggests their email. If the user selects the auto suggestion it ads a trailing blank space at the end. then when the user goes to signup the system says invalid email because of the blank space. users dont always see the blank space. How can I remove the trailing blank space automatically.

I already have a piece of js that uses the check this function to compare email address entered for repeat email.

```
<form name="account_reg_form" method="post" action="{$rlBase}{if $config.mod_rewrite}{$pageInfo.Path}.html{else}?page={$pageInfo.Path}{/if}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <input style="text-transform:lowercase;" id="eMail" size="45" class="wauto" type="text" name="profile[mail]" {if $smarty.post.profile.mail}value="{$smarty.post.profile.mail}"{/if} required oninput="check(this)" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <input size="45" class="wauto" id="eMail_repeat" type="text" name="email_addr_repeat" title="Repeat your email address" placeholder="Repeat your email address" required oninput="check(this)" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="{$lang.next_step}" />
</form>
<script>
    function check() {
        var email = document.getElementById('eMail');
        var emailRepeat = document.getElementById('eMail_repeat');

        if (email.value != emailRepeat.value) {
            emailRepeat.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
        } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message 
            emailRepeat.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
</script>
<input style="text-transform:lowercase;" id="eMail" size="45" class="wauto" type="text" name="profile[mail]" {if $smarty.post.profile.mail}value="{$smarty.post.profile.mail}"{/if} required oninput="check(this)" />
```

Comment: Use `trim()` function

Comment: Maybe this helps when using jquery: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Thanks for the reply lads. Im gonna be cheeky and ask can you give me a working demo as Im a plank at this stuff. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Just use the Jquery snippet below so that, even if you select an email with spaces, it will be trimmed using the `input bind event`.

It even will not allow spaces.

```js
$(function(){
  $('#eMail').bind('change', function(){
    $(this).val(function(_, v){
     return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });
  });
  
  $('#eMail_repeat').bind('change', function(){
    $(this).val(function(_, v){
     return v.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="email" id="eMail"/>
<input type="email" id="eMail_repeat"/>
```

**Pls run the code snippet, paste any email with spaces directly, and it automatically trim's the spaces.**

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bqht7nha/1/)

Comment: Awesome that works. just one wired issue. when using android after entering the email address, if i try to single space delete a character. for example if I type dem1o@demo.com and need to delete the 1 as it may have been a mistake. when I place the cursor to the right of the 1 and tap delete the cursor jumps to the end of the email. This is only on Android.

Comment: @AidenDoyle, please check now, thee email will get trimmed when you move from input box and your issue in android also resolved.

Answer (score 0):

```
var email = document.getElementById("eMail").value.trim();
var repeat = document.getElementById("eMail_repeat").value.trim();
```

demo can be found [here](http://js.do/code/115271). Enter whitespace after the email inputs to check.

edit: Clearer demo can be found [here](http://js.do/code/115290), with sample addresses provided, and highlighting the differences between using .trim() and not using it.

Comment: wrong..........

Comment: you'd have to add ".value" before your ".trim()": i.e. var email = document.getElementById('eMail').value.trim();

Comment: apologies - have updated my reply accordingly.

Comment: thanks mike but your demo does not trim...?

Comment: It should do. I've updated my original reply with a (hopefully) clearer demo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javascript's `String.replace` with this regex `/\s+$/`. It would replace the text with empty string.

`string.replace(/\s+$/, '')`

Example:

```
var testString = "      test string      ";
console.log(testString.replace(/\s+$/, '');  // logs: "     test string"
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/tanmayrajani/pen/dpLPba?editors=0010#0)

**Note:** We could have used the `trim()` function directly but it removes leading as well as trailing spaces whereas we want only trailing. [`trimLeft`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/TrimLeft) and [`trimRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trimRight) are neither standerdized nor implemented in *all* browsers.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. yet again excuse my ignorance but could you give me a working demo of what you suggest. As I mentioned above im a plank at this stuff. cheers.

Comment: @AidenDoyle check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

you can use $.trim() function here:

```
<form name="account_reg_form" method="post" action="{$rlBase}{if $config.mod_rewrite}{$pageInfo.Path}.html{else}?page={$pageInfo.Path}{/if}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <input style="text-transform:lowercase;" id="eMail" size="45" class="wauto" type="text" name="profile[mail]" {if $smarty.post.profile.mail}value="{$smarty.post.profile.mail}"{/if} required oninput="check(this)" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:10px;">
        <input size="45" class="wauto" id="eMail_repeat" type="text" name="email_addr_repeat" title="Repeat your email address" placeholder="Repeat your email address" required oninput="check(this)" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="{$lang.next_step}" />
</form>
<script>
    function check() {
        var email = document.getElementById('eMail').value.trim();
        var emailRepeat = document.getElementById('eMail_repeat').value.trim();

        if (email.value != emailRepeat.value) {
            emailRepeat.setCustomValidity('The two email addresses must match.');
        } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message 
            emailRepeat.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
</script>
<input style="text-transform:lowercase;" id="eMail" size="45" class="wauto" type="text" name="profile[mail]" {if $smarty.post.profile.mail}value="{$smarty.post.profile.mail}"{/if} required oninput="check(this)" />
```